# calculate difference in days lagged one year forward

Tags: r, tidyr, lubridate

I have a table with id's and stop and start dates. I need to mutate a new column called "running_time_in_days" that finds the difference from one year's start date to the next years stop state for each id (the process carries over Jan 1, so the duration is over the new year).

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# read in some test data
test <- read_csv("id, measure, measure_date
        1, start, 1998-10-3 
        1, stop, 1999-5-1
        1, stop, 2000-4-15
        1, start, 1999-11-9
        2, stop, 2000-6-1
        2, stop, 1999-5-25
        2, start, 1999-12-1 
        2, start, 1998-11-12")
# format "measure_date" as a date
test$measure_date <- test$measure_date %>% as_date('%Y-%m-%d')
```

The output could look something like this in wide form:

```
    id      start       stop        duration
    1   1998-10-03  1999-05-01  stop - start (days)
    1   1999-05-01  2000-04-15  stop - start (days)
    2   1998-11-12  1999-05-25  stop - start (days)
    2   1999-12-01  2000-06-01  stop - start (days)
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
test %>% 
  # create unique row identifier for wide form, since there are
  # multiple start / stop dates associated with each id
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(measure_date) %>% 
  mutate(id2 = rep(seq(1, n()/2), each = 2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 

  # convert to wide form & calculate difference between dates
  tidyr::spread(measure, measure_date) %>% 
  mutate(duration = difftime(stop, start, "days")) %>% 
  select(-id2)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id start      stop       duration
  <dbl> <date>     <date>     <drtn>  
1     1 1998-10-03 1999-05-01 210 days
2     1 1999-11-09 2000-04-15 158 days
3     2 1998-11-12 1999-05-25 194 days
4     2 1999-12-01 2000-06-01 183 days
```